# Where is Brown's lemma from?

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, model-categories

In homotopy theory, Kenneth Brown's lemma states that if a functor send acyclic cofibrations between cofibrant objects to weak equivalences, then it send all weak equivalences between cofibrant objets to weak equivalences. It's cited in a lot of places (e.g. Lemma 1.1.12 in Hovey's *Model categories*). It's a pretty nice lemma.

Where is it actually from? Where did Kenneth Brown write it down? (Brown has 41 publications on MathSciNet, I'm a bit wary of diving in to find it, so perhaps someone knows off the top of their head... And of course I doubt he's going to call it "Brown's lemma" himself, so I can't just search for that in his papers.)

Comment: If I recall correctly, it was in his PhD thesis. I can look later if I find time.

Comment: @DavidWhite Thanks, I will look it up.

Comment: (If anyone is wondering about the edit: I had initially looked at K. A. Brown's page on mathscinet when I should have looked at K. S. Brown's page.)

Comment: I've always heard this lemma referred to as "Ken Brown's Lemma" rather than just "Brown's Lemma". Apparently, though, that's still not sufficient to clarify which Brown we're referring to!

Answer (score 2):

See page 428 of [Abstract homotopy theory and generalized sheaf cohomology](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/scan/1973.0186.pdf) (1973):

[image]

Comment: I must be missing something but I don't see how this is equivalent to what is usually called Brown's lemma... In the context of categories of fibrant objets, I guess Brown's lemma says that if $F$ sends acyclic fibrations to weak equivalences, then it sends weak equivalences to weak equivalences. Here the functor does not just send acyclic fibrations to weak equivalences, it also sends fibrations to fibrations.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi --- see the discussion following proposition 2.6 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02456

Comment: I think I'd take the "Factorization Lemma" in the paper Carlo links to to be a pretty definitive statement of Ken Brown's Lemma. At any rate, the perspective I've seen taken before is that the statement about functors between categories of fibrant objects is an easy corollary (which it is!). And the lemma that Carlo refers to is an instance thereof.